# Android como remover a opção "Fotos" do seletor de opções e deixar somente as opções "Câmera" e "Galeria"

Tags: android, galeria, intent

Gostaria de saber como remover a opção "Fotos" do seletor de opções e deixar somente as opções "Câmera" e "Galeria". Pois além de não funcionar, é desnecessária  já que a "Galeria" faz a mesma coisa e melhor. Abaixo segue meu código e o resultado:

**Activity EditarContaActivity:**

```
public class EditarContaActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;    
Button btneditar;   
File file;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editarconta);

    imguser = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgdefault_user);

    btneditar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btneditar1);
    btneditar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_editarconta, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    //Detects request codes
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        imguser.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        String filename = "profile.jpg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        Intent testeIntent = CarregarImagem.pegaIntencao(this, file);

        startActivityForResult(testeIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }   

}
```

**Classe CarregarImagem:**

```
public class CarregarImagem {   

public static Intent pegaIntencao(Context contexto, File file) {

    // Intenção da Câmera
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = contexto.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Intenção da Galeria
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // Seletor de opções
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Foto de Perfil");

    // Add opção de camera 
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

    return chooserIntent;

}
```

}

**Resultado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, com a ajuda da resposta e os comentários do @Pablo cheguei a conclusão de que a melhor prática é fazer funcionar, porém deve ter alguma forma de verificar se uma das opções que o app vai exibir está funcionando antes de exibir e assim se não estiver ele não exibe essa opção, como o que ocorre com o WattsApp que não exibe essa opção no meu celular e exibe nos outros e no app do código dessa pergunta ele exibe, porém da erro. Dessa forma vou tentar fazer funcionar e tentar fazer ele verificar as opções funcionais antes de exibir. Obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer isso. Quem define o que aparece aí é o Android, baseado no tipo de Intent que você passou e em quais aplicações estão escutando esse tipo de ação. Quem deve decidir se essa opção é relevante ou não é o(a) usuário(a), clicando em "Sempre" (quando disponível) ou desinstalando/desativando a aplicação.

Comment: Mas o watts app não permite aparecer esta opção, acho que é pq ela não funciona, tanto que quando eu clico nela aparece as fotos, porém ao selecionar qualquer foto o app causa um erro.

Comment: Acabei de verificar aqui que o WhatsApp exibe um monte de aplicativos pra escolher, incluindo o Fotos:

( https://i.imgur.com/pdAHuLh.jpg )

Se o Fotos não funciona para a ação que você quer, é esse o problema que você tem que resolver. Mesmo que você consiga, não é bom limitar as preferências do(a) usuário(a). Eu também já tive esse problema uma vez e fiz funcionar. Você também consegue.

Comment: você verificou isso aonde? Porque eu estava falando na parte onde você vai mudar a foto de perfil e não na parte de mandar mensagens.

Comment: Essa parte fica em configurações/Perfil.

Comment: Fui em configurações/perfil.

Comment: Sério porque no meu não aparece essa opção, aparece só galeria, câmera e a opção de remover foto, já quando vou executar o app desse projeto aparece.

Comment: Acabei de verificar em outro celular aqui e essa opção aparece, acho que está opção de Fotos do meu celular é que não está funcionando ou o Watts App verifica se a opção vai funcionar primeiro antes de exibir. Realmente não sei como eu faria este tipo de verificação se for o caso.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante Abra uma outra pergunta especificamente para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Desta maneira não aparece a camara:

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
 final Intent chooserIntent =
                Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Um texto qualquer");
 startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Não te esqueças que o REQUEST_CODE_LOAD_IMAGE é uma constante definida por ti que será usada no metodo onActivityResult.

Comment: Mas não é a câmera que eu queria tirar era a opção "Fotos". Mas valew pela atenção.

Comment: Desculpa entendi mal. De qualquer maneira vou deixar ficar a resposta, pode ajudar alguem.

Para a câmara podes tentar Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);